# What is the theme that makes MacOS terminal prompt a green greater than symbol?

Tags: macos, terminal, themes

I've seen many devs on YouTube use this prompt. It changes to red when there's an error which is nice.

[image]

I've been searching for it but couldn't find it. I've looked at `ohmyzsh` themes but couldn't find it.

Comment: Good question. Perhaps look into Oh My ZSH themes?

Comment: I have. Couldn't find it.

Comment: Hmm. Well, for what it’s worth, that’s not a greater than symbol, not quite. That might sound pedantic and unhelpful, but it’s actually a clue! I suspect it may be a "powerline" symbol. (The shape is called a chevron.) So… Maybe search for 'powerline prompt hacks' or similar?

Comment: Or maybe it’s _not_ powerline. "Powerline alternatives"?

Comment: No, I think it _is_ the powerline symbol `e0b1`

Comment: This might not be exactly what you want, but it probably has all the pieces you need. Note how the color changes based on the last command status. https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell